# How to apply a custom analyzer to an elastic search index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to create a custom analyzer for an index so that the tokens and generated using this custom index.

I tried to do the following

```json
PUT /index_name/_settings
{
  "analysis" : {
    "analyzer":{
      "custom_analyzer_name": {
          "type": "custom", 
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop"
          ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

That gives me this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Can't update non dynamic settings [[index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.char_filter, index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.filter, index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.type, index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.tokenizer]] for open indices [[index_name/Zd4fisCyR6alpkzj-6uSgQ]]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Can't update non dynamic settings [[index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.char_filter, index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.filter, index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.type, index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.tokenizer]] for open indices [[index_name/Zd4fisCyR6alpkzj-6uSgQ]]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I also tried to create the analyzer like this

```
PUT /index_name
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_analyzer_name": {
          "type": "custom", 
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But that gives me the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason": "index [index_name/Zd4fisCyR6alpkzj-6uSgQ] already exists",
        "index_uuid": "Zd4fisCyR6alpkzj-6uSgQ",
        "index": "index_name"
      }
    ],
    "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
    "reason": "index [index_name/Zd4fisCyR6alpkzj-6uSgQ] already exists",
    "index_uuid": "Zd4fisCyR6alpkzj-6uSgQ",
    "index": "index_name"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

How can I correctly create and assign the custom analyzer in Elasticsearch index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the errors you get, `index_name` already exists, so you cannot recreate it unless you delete it first.

If you can't delete it, but only want to [modify the analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis), you can do so by closing the index first and then re-opening it:

```
POST index_name/_close

PUT /index_name/_settings
{
  "analysis" : {
    "analyzer":{
      "custom_analyzer_name": {
          "type": "custom", 
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop"
          ]
        }
    }
  }
}

POST index_name/_open
```

You might need to have to run this before closing your index

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.indices.close.enable": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help. This gives me yet another error `illegal_argument_exception` the error says `Can't update non dynamic settings [[index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.char_filter, index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.filter, index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.type, index.analysis.analyzer.custom_analyzer_name.tokenizer]] for open indices [[index_name/Zd4fisCyR6alpkzj-6uSgQ]`

Comment: Because you haven't close it first

Comment: I have. I did this first `POST index_name/_close` and when I do I get this `{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "shards_acknowledged": false,
  "indices": {}
}`